# Подойдет ли Redis для данных, которые нежелательно терять?

Tags: redis

Ищу хранилище типа ключ - список значений. Redis очень хорошо подходит, но я ни разу его не использовал до этого, но наслышан много. Часто говорят что Redis это прямой путь к потерянным данным. Так ли это? Насколько высока вероятность что либо потерять на практике и насколько много данных теряется?

https://redis.io/topics/persistence - здесь вроде пишут, что можно установить AOF на каждый запрос, значит ли это, что я теперь не потеряю свои данные или на практике все не так красиво?

В общем подойдет ли Redis для данных, которые нежелательно терять?

Answer (score 0):

Redis не предназначен для гарантированного хранения данных. В первую очередь это inmemory database. Все данные во время работы хранятся в памяти. Дамп на диск сохраняется асинхронно.
Соответственно, сбой сервера между дампами, нехватка памяти - все это приведет к потере части данных.
Основные области применения: кэш, промежуточные вычисления, хранение сессий и т.д.

Тем не менее, если у вас несколько серверов Redis, настроена репликация и маловероятна ситуация, когда все сервера отключатся, то можете попробовать. https://habr.com/post/178525/